# onClick is not working in Styled component in react

Tags: reactjs, components, styled-components

I am trying to implement a dropdown in react styled component. I am trying to set the submenu onClick. But on click function is not getting called. I want to set submenu on click of SidebarLink component. and display the dropdown submenu

I tried this https://github.com/styled-components/vue-styled-components/issues/22
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-responsive-sidebar-with-dropdown-menu-in-reactjs/

SidebarData

```
import React from "react";

export const SidebarData = [
  {
    title: "Feeds",
    path: "/feeds",
    icon: "Images/images/feed_inactive.svg",
    iconsrc: "Images/images/feed_active.svg",
  },
  {
    title: "Groups",
    path: "/groups",
    icon: "Images/images/notactive_people.svg",
    iconsrc: "Images/images/icon_ionic_ios_people.svg",
    subNav: [
      {
        title: "All",
        status: "all",
        cName: "sub-nav",
      },
      {
        title: "Have met",
        status: "met",
        cName: "sub-nav",
      },
      {
        title: "Favorite",
        status: "fav",
        cName: "sub-nav",
      },
      {
        title: "Expired",
        status: "expired",
        cName: "sub-nav",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Chats",
    path: "/chats",
    icon: "Images/images/notactive_chat_bubble.svg",
    iconsrc: "Images/images/icon_material_chat_bubble.svg",
    subNav: [
      {
        title: "Open Threads",
        cName: "sub-nav",
        status: "threads",
      },
      {
        title: "Favorite",
        cName: "sub-nav",
        status: "favMem",
      },
      {
        title: "Expired",
        cName: "sub-nav",
        status: "expChat",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Event",
    path: "/event",
    icon: "Images/images/intersection_51.svg",
    iconsrc: "Images/images/intersection_act.svg",
  },
];
```

SidebarLink

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";

const SidebarLink = styled.button`
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;

  &:hover {
    background: #252831;
    border-left: 4px solid green;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const SidebarLabel = styled.span`
  margin-left: 16px;
`;

const DropdownLink = styled(Link)`
  background: #252831;
  height: 60px;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;

  &:hover {
    background: green;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;
const SubMenu = (props) => {
  const [subnavigation, setSubnavigation] = useState(false);
  const showSubnav = () => {
    console.log("ddjhj");
    setSubnavigation(!subnavigation);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("subnav", subnavigation);
  }, [subnavigation]);
  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLink onClick={showSubnav}>
        {props.item.title}
        <span>
          {" "}
          {props.item.path === window.location.pathname ? (
            <Image src={props.item.iconsrc} />
          ) : (
            <Image src={props.item.icon} />
          )}
        </span>
      </SidebarLink>

      {subnavigation &&
        props.item.subNav.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <DropdownLink onClick={() => props.status(item.status)} key={index}>
              {item.icon}
              <SidebarLabel>{item.title}</SidebarLabel>
            </DropdownLink>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default SubMenu;
```

Sidebar

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import * as FaIcons from "react-icons/fa";
import * as AiIcons from "react-icons/ai";
import { SidebarData } from "./SidebarData";
import SubMenu from "./SubMenu";
import { IconContext } from "react-icons/lib";
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import { MdAccountBalanceWallet } from "react-icons/md";
import { getUserProfile } from "../../../Redux/Slices/DashboardSlice";
import { getPoints, logout } from "../../../Redux/Slices/SidebarSlice";
import {
  sidebarToggle,
  statusCheck,
  userProfile,
} from "../../../Contexts/context";
import "./sidebar.css";
import Loading from "../../../Functions/Loading";

const NavIcon = styled(Link)`
  margin-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
`;

const SidebarNav = styled.nav`
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  transition: 350ms;
  z-index: 10;
`;

const SidebarWrap = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
`;

const Sidebar = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { sidebarShow, setSidebarShow } = useContext(sidebarToggle);
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { UserData, setUserData } = useContext(userProfile);
  const [Points, setPoints] = useState();
  const { Status, setStatus } = useContext(statusCheck);
  const statusChecked = (status) => {
    switch (status) {
      case "expired":
        return setStatus({
          all: false,
          fav: false,
          met: false,
          expired: true,
        });
      case "met":
        return setStatus({
          all: false,
          fav: false,
          met: true,
          expired: false,
        });
      case "fav":
        return setStatus({
          all: false,
          fav: true,
          met: false,
          expired: false,
        });
      case "threads":
        return setStatus({
          favMem: false,
          threads: true,
          expChat: false,
        });
      case "favMem":
        return setStatus({
          favMem: true,
          threads: false,
          expChat: false,
        });
      case "expChat":
        return setStatus({
          favMem: false,
          threads: false,
          expChat: true,
        });
      default:
        return setStatus({
          all: true,
          threads: true,
          fav: false,
          met: false,
          expired: false,
        });
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUserProfile()).then((response) =>
      setUserData(response.payload && response.payload.userprofile)
    );
    dispatch(getPoints()).then((response) =>
      setPoints(response.payload && response.payload.points)
    );
  }, []);
  const logOut = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    dispatch(logout()).then((response) => {
      setLoading(false);
      window.location.replace("/");
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: "#fff" }}>
        <div
          className={
            sidebarShow
              ? " vertical-nav bg-white mt-5"
              : "vertical-nav bg-white active mt-5"
          }
          id="sidebar"
        >
          <SidebarNav>
            <SidebarWrap>
              {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
                return <SubMenu item={item} key={index} />;
              })}
            </SidebarWrap>
          </SidebarNav>
        </div>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Is the `onClick` of a `button` *really* not working, or is there something further down the line that is failing? Do you see the `console.log("ddjhj");` log to the console? Do you have the React dev tools extension installed so you can inspect component state to ensure it's toggling?

Comment: No console.log("ddjhj"); is not getting logged.
onClick={()=>showSubnav()} I even tried this to call showSubnav function

Comment: Could you try to create a *running* codesandbox that we can inspect live and debug in? I see no reason why a button wouldn't be clickable from your snippet.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-hooks-uugw0?file=/src/SubMenu.js

Comment: They are clickable for me. I see the submenu open on the middle two menus, and when I add back in the `console.log("ddjhj");` in the `showSubnav` handler I see it logging as expected.

Comment: I think the problem is something else. I have a vertical sidebar .
     .vertical-nav {
    min-width: 17rem;
    width: 17rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
when i remove position: relative dropdown menu appears